# Is this the correct way to make an if statement for my rotating node?

Tags: ios, swift, touchesmoved

I'm able to rotate my node with one finger but I'm having trouble with my `if` statement. I have an `if` statement to add an action if I'm rotating to the left or right. I'm priniting to the console `print("rotate right")` when I'm rotating to the right and `print("rotate left")` when I'm rotating to the left. The problem I'm having is when I rotate to the right there's a spot where I rotate that prints "rotate left" and on the same spot the same thing happens when I rotate to the left it prints "rotate right". Why does that happen?

EDIT here is a picture of the spot.

[image]

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches {
        var previousAngle: CGFloat = 0.0
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

        if node.name == "circle" {
            if lastNodeSelected != nil {
                let touchedNode = lastNodeSelected!

                //lets user rotate with one finger.
                let dy = touchedNode.position.y - location.y
                let dx = touchedNode.position.x - location.x
                let angle2 = atan2(dy, dx)
                touchedNode.zRotation =  angle2

                let delta = (angle2 - previousAngle)
                if delta > 0 {
                    print("rotate left")
                }
                else {
                    print("rotate right")
                }
                previousAngle = angle2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "theres a spot where I rotate that prints ...", It might help to tell us which spot. Your `if ... else` is not doing what you think (nesting is incorrect).... it should be like `if this { then } else { that }` ...

Comment: I added a pic and I made a mistake copying my code of the if statement I fixed it now.

Comment: What is the value when it's at the spot you mention?

Comment: I get different values when I get to that spot its all in the 6. and greater when I rotate to the right and 0. and greater when I rotate to the left.

Comment: Theres not like a value thats the same when I rotate to the spot. Its a different number every time.

Comment: That doesnt work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`atan2` gives results from -π to π, so there’s a transition point where the value jumps by 2π (or -2π, depending on the direction you’re going).

To make this work in the general case, you can’t just subtract angles; you need to figure out whether `angle2` is closer to `previousAngle` moving clockwise or counterclockwise.

Try:

```
func rotationDelta(fromAngle a0: Double, toAngle a1: Double) -> Double {
    let π = M_PI
    return ((a1 - a0) % (2*π) + 3*π) % (2*π) - π
}
```

…and then:

```
let delta = rotationDelta(fromAngle: previousAngle, toAngle: angle2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but how do I figure that out?

Comment: I get an error for angle2 saying `cannot convert value of type CGFloat to expected argument type Double`

Comment: Yes, you’ll need to cast the result to `CGFloat` (or change the function itself to take & return that type). Swift is very strict about any numeric conversion that might result in loss of precision. https://www.google.com/search?q=swift+cast+numeric+type

Comment: I have a question am I supposed to make it into a `if let` statement? I get an error when I do that saying `Intializer for conditional binding must have Optional value not Bool`

Comment: I have to wait 23 hours to give you the bounty, I won't forget.

Comment: I casted it like this btw `let delta = rotationDelta(fromAngle: Double(previousAngle), toAngle: Double(angle2)) > 0`